# The typedef struct function is not working

Tags: c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykTh8.jpg)I am trying to create my own data type, but for some reason it just wouldn't work.

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[20];
    char number[20];
} Person;
```

This should create a data type called (person) that takes a name and a string number.
Edit : still not working[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCp9p.jpg)

[Here is the compiler massage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCp9p.jpg)

Comment: You're missing the `struct` keyword. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71270954/how-to-properly-use-typedef-for-structs-in-c

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Where did you learn that you have to write the code like this?

Comment: If you get some warnings or error messages from your compiler, please always show them. Copy&paste the complete and exact message into your question.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the word `struct`

`typedef` is used to give a new name to an old type:

```c
typedef int my_int;
```

This typesdefs `my_int` to be int.

```c
struct person {
   int x;
   char name[20];
};

typedef struct person person_t;
```

This creates a struct called `person`, and then typedefs `person_t` to mean `struct person`.

```c
typedef struct person {
   int x;
   char name[20];
} person_t;
```

This does the same thing as the snippet before, but in one step.

```c
typedef struct {
   int x;
   char name[20];
} person_t;
```

This typedefs `person_t` to *an unnamed* struct, that you defined as so. This is what you were trying to do, you were just missing the `struct` after the `typedef`